# Trouble involving class functions

Tags: c++, function, class, parameters

I am having trouble passing a class parameter through a function in main.I have the syntax for the print function correct. The function that im having trouble with is passing f2 into the fracmult function. If anyone has any explanation or ideas for code that would cause the numerators and denoms to be multipled of f1 and f2 together that would be excellent. Note: this is my first time working with classes

```
class fraction

{
    private:
        int numerator;
        int denom;
        bool positive;

    public:
        void inputFrac();
        void printFrac();

        fraction fracMult(fraction b);
        fraction fracDiv(fraction b);
        fraction fracAdd(fraction b);
        fraction fracSub(fraction b);
};

 void fraction::printFrac()
{
    if (!positive)
    {
    cout << "-";
    }
    cout << numerator << " / " << denom;
}
void fraction::inputFrac()
{    
    cout<<"Please input the numerator ";
    cin>>numerator;
    cout<< "Please input the denominator ";
    cin>>denom; 
    cout<<"Is the fraction positive? (Y or N);
    cin>>positive;
}

 fraction fraction::fracMult(fraction b)
{

     numerator=b.numerator;
     denom=b.denom;
}
fraction fraction::fracAdd(fraction& b)
 {
     fraction temp; 
     temp.numerator=numerator + b.numerator;
     temp.denom=denom + b.denom;

     return temp;
 }
 fraction fraction::fracDiv(fraction& b)
 {
     fraction temp;
     temp.numerator = numerator * b.denom;
     temp.denom = denom * b.numerator;

     return temp;

 }
 fraction fraction::fracSub(fraction& b)
 {

    fraction temp;
     temp.numerator = numerator - b.numerator;
     temp.denom = denom - b.denom;

     return temp;   
 }

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    fraction f1, f2, fresult;

    f1.inputFrac(); //input the first fraction
    f2.inputFrac(); //input the second fraction
    cout<<endl;
    f1.printFrac();
    cout<<endl;
    f2.printFrac();
    cout<<endl;

    cout << "The result of a * b is: ";

    fresult = f1.fracMult(f2); // calculate a * b
    fresult.printFrac(); // print out the result
```

Comment: What *exactly* is the issue?  Compiler error?  Runtime error?

Comment: runtime error. Say i the values i enter end up as f1.numerator =1 f1.denom =2 f2.numerator=3 and f2.denom = 4 and then i perform the f1.fracmult(f2) function it ends up as like -1650232 / 0 so I need help with the proper code

Comment: Please don't give extra information in comments, add it to your post by clicking on `edit`

Comment: Does anyone have any information on how to get the proper sign to be displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in fraction::fracMult you need to have this:

```
fraction fraction::fracMult( const fraction& b)
{
    if(positive==b.positive) positive=false;

    numerator *=b.numerator;
    denom *=b.denom;

    return *this;
}
```

alternatively you could have:

```
fraction fraction::fracMult(const fraction&b) const
{
  fraction output;
  output.numerator = this->numerator *b.numerator;
  output.denom = this->denom *b.denom ;
  output.positive=false;
  if(this->positive==b.positive) output.positive=true;

  return output;

}
```

Comment: Would be a bad idea, because that way you would alter the original object (this). Better if you create a new object, calculate its respective values and return the new object instead of *this.

Comment: that is a design decision. alternatively he could have a static function that takes two fractions by const reference as parameter and returns their product. I opted for this option because he already had assignment set for all the fields

Comment: When I tried to do all the codes for the 4 operators, I am only able to return the first type( which is *) now my problem is trying to get all the functions to be returned in main

Comment: what do you mean? are you trying to implement addition and subtraction? the basis of your function signatures will remain the same (whichever design you will choose). alternatively you could overload + - * and / operators but that's a little more advanced.

Comment: Exactly, Im trying to perform all 4 operators on the 2 fractions through 4 different functions and have them all returned in main, but currently only the first operator which is * is being returned

Comment: first of all functions do not get "returned" in main, calls to functions that return a value will return the aforementioned value to the function that called in (in this case for you the caller is the main function). you have not provided any code for your other operations but the function signature for all functions will be similar.

Comment: I posted the rest of my functions in the post, the internal of the functions looks the same as the mult function, just different operators. But after the mult function is performed and returned, the next three do no appear when then program runs

Comment: it is because you set fresult only one time for multiplication and print fresult only ONE TIME in your main function. you are only defining the other three functions you are never making any calls to them. how can you expect for them to magically display results?

Comment: I just caught that right before you posted, another stupid user error :P

Comment: good, make sure to have your function signatures set correctly. (const fraction &other) const.   the first const says that you are not modifying the other fraction that is passed in. the second const says that you are not modifying the object on which the function is being called. these are not necessary for your code to run, but following good practice will save your bacon one day

Comment: Thank you, and the last thing is applying the positive and negative to make sure the function gets the correct sign

Comment: since you have only 1 reputation im guessing you are new here. you should select a best answer when you receive them

Comment: I selected yours as the best answer. I just need some assistance getting the positive and negative for the fractions

Comment: do you know how to add fractions on paper? if so, it is not going to be difficult. you need the LCD (which need GCD) , but if your numbers are not too big you can just use the product of the denominators as your common divisor. this is a completely math related question the programming should be straight forward

Comment: Ill make sure to change those, but Are you able to help me to figure out how to get the proper sign for the fractions

Answer (score 0):

When you compiled your code, was there a warning specifying that you were exiting a function that expected a return of a value, but did not return a value?

```
fraction fraction::fracMult(fraction b)
{
     numerator=b.numerator;
     denom=b.denom;
}
```

You have defined a function that returns a `fraction`, but you failed to return a value.  Thus the function produces *undefined behavior*.

The fix is to return the fraction object.

```
fraction fraction::fracMult(fraction b)
{
     numerator=b.numerator;
     denom=b.denom;
     return *this;
}
```

However, this seems counter-intuitive.  If you're going to multiply an object by a value and return a new `fraction`, then a copy of `this` must be created, and then return the copy.  You don't want to alter the current fraction.

```
fraction fraction::fracMult(fraction b)
{
     fraction temp(*this); 
     temp.numerator=b.numerator;
     temp.denom=b.denom;
     return temp;
}
```

If you really did want to alter the current fraction, then return a reference to `*this`, not a new object:

```
fraction& fraction::fracMult(fraction b)
{
     numerator=b.numerator;
     denom=b.denom;
     return *this;
}
```

But this is why there is `operator *` and `operator *=`.  You need to decide which of these operations your function is supposed to be performing.  Either altering the current object, or computing using the current object's data and returning a new object.

Comment: correct, but you also needed to account for the signs

Comment: is there a way to do this without pointers? we have not learned these yet

Comment: @John There are no pointers in the answer I presented.  And that is a *good* thing -- there is no need for pointers whatsoever in your `fraction` class.

Comment: *  in *this is dereference operator because "this" is an implicit pointer that refers to the object for which the non-static function is called. there are no explicit pointers in Paul's answer. this is the only way for you to return "your own object" inside a method

Comment: @John - Hopefully you understand  that your issue consisted of *two* problems, the main one being you not returning a value.  Without a `return`, it doesn't matter if the code without the return computed the item correctly.  Without the return, your program may have just crashed, or returned the wrong results even if you computed the correct ones.  So maybe your fraction class decides to do some sort of funky multiplication?  Doesn't matter, as it was not the focus  -- what matters is that you can't call a function that expects a return value, and not return a value.

Comment: When I tried to do all the codes for the 4 operators, I am only able to return the first type( which is *) now my problem is trying to get all the functions to be returned in main

Answer (score 0):

```
class fraction
{
private:
    int numerator;
    int denom;
char choice;

public:
void inputFrac();
void printFrac();

fraction fracMult(fraction b);
fraction fracDiv(fraction b);
fraction fracAdd(fraction b);
fraction fracSub(fraction b);
}; 

void fraction::printFrac()
{
if (choice=='y'||choice=='Y')
{
cout << "-";
}
cout << numerator << " / " << denom;
}
void fraction::inputFrac()
{
 cout<<"Please input the numerator ";
cin>>numerator;
cout<< "Please input the denominator ";
cin>>denom;
cout<<"Is the fraction positive? (y or n)";
cin>>choice;
}

fraction fraction::fracMult(fraction b)
{

 fraction temp;
temp.numerator=numerator*b.numerator;
 temp.denom=denom*b.denom;
 return temp;
 }
 fraction fraction::fracAdd(fraction b)
 {
 fraction temp;
 temp.numerator=numerator + b.numerator;
 temp.denom=denom + b.denom;

 return temp;
 }
 fraction fraction::fracDiv(fraction b)
 {
 fraction temp;
 temp.numerator = numerator * b.denom;
 temp.denom = denom * b.numerator;

 return temp;

  }
 fraction fraction::fracSub(fraction b)
 {

 fraction temp;
 temp.numerator = numerator - b.numerator;
 temp.denom = denom - b.denom;

 return temp;
  }

 int main(int argc, char** argv) {

 fraction f1, f2, fresult;

f1.inputFrac(); //input the first fraction
f2.inputFrac(); //input the second fraction
cout<<endl;
f1.printFrac();
cout<<endl;
f2.printFrac();
cout<<endl;

cout << "The result of a * b is: ";

fresult = f1.fracMult(f2); // calculate a * b
fresult.printFrac(); // print out the result
}
```

Comment: I used this method and it worked, how will I adjust now for the correct sign?